# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop for subchild DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to map a return statement with multiple child components and getting ESLint error

```
    console.error
      Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

This is my React Code:

```html
const EmployeeDetails = ({ employeeid }) => {
    return (
            <div>
            <strong>Employee Overview Details</strong>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-container" key="test">
            {employeeOverviewDetails.map((detail, index) => {
            return (
            <>
            {detail.heading === 'Employee ID' && (
            <div
                className="indiviual-flex"
                key={index}
                >
                <small key={detail.heading}>
                {detail.heading}
                </small>
                <br />
                <strong key={detail.value}>
                {employeeid}
                </strong>
            </div>
            )}
            {detail.heading !== 'Employee ID' && (
            <div
                className="indiviual-flex"
                key={detail.heading}
                >
                <small>{detail.heading}</small>
                <br />
                <strong>{detail.value}</strong>
            </div>
            )}
            </>
            )
            })}
            </div>
    )
}
```

I am passing key for every element and yet ESLint keeps warning about unique "key" prop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: And the official documentation on topic is clear on this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I am seen the docs. Issue/warning still persists even after adding the `key` property

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a fragment:

```js
const EmployeeDetails = ({ employeeid }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <strong>Employee Overview Details</strong>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-container" key="test">
        {employeeOverviewDetails.map((detail, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              {detail.heading === "Employee ID" && (
                <div className="indiviual-flex" key={index}>
                  <small key={detail.heading}>{detail.heading}</small>
                  <br />
                  <strong key={detail.value}>{employeeid}</strong>
                </div>
              )}
              {detail.heading !== "Employee ID" && (
                <div className="indiviual-flex" key={detail.heading}>
                  <small>{detail.heading}</small>
                  <br />
                  <strong>{detail.value}</strong>
                </div>
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

You cannot have 2 elements side by side in React, either use this syntax

```js
<> </>
```

to wrap around the elements which are side by side or use you can import `Fragment` from React like this:

```js
import { Fragment } from "react";
```

And then wrap the elements which are side by side with `Fragment` like this:

```js
<Fragment></Fragment>
```

or if u don't want to import `Fragment` you can also use `React.Fragment`. but you need to import react for this.